# How to request Redis server using a streaming input PCollection in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, redis, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, flink-streaming

Using [RedisIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/redis/RedisIO.html), I'm trying to query a collection to a redis server.

The Redis server is ok and responding good only when batch pipeline (no streaming).

But, using streaming input data (from files) like this:

```
  PCollection<String> stream = pipeline.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from("/home/out/**")
  .watchForNewFiles(Duration.standardSeconds(60), Watch.Growth.<String>never()))   
  .apply("ParseFn", ParDo.of(new ParseFn()))
  .apply("GlobalString", GlobalString.get(Duration.ZERO, Duration.standardSeconds(60)));
```

And then, apply the redisIO read() function:

```
 PCollection<KV<String, String>> redis = stream.apply(RedisIO.readAll().withEndpoint("127.0.0.1", 6379));
```

Finally, want to use the result collection, so:

```
 PCollection<String> result = redis.apply("Compose Final Object", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, String>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      System.out.println(c.element().getKey());
      c.output(c.element().getKey());
    }
  }));
```

As far as I tested, the files are being loaded and processed as needed.

Comment: I can't understand your issue very well, Is your pipeline failing using streaming? What is your use case? What is the format of the files you are trying to process? Give an example please.

Comment: @OscarR, the files are read and I can build a PCollection of strings. There is no error throw, but the ParDo never triggers.

Comment: If I remove the `.watchForNewFiles(Duration.standardSeconds(60), Watch.Growth.<String>never())) ` line, it works as expected

Comment: By the other hand, if I remove the `PCollection<KV<String, String>> redis = stream.apply(RedisIO.readAll().withEndpoint("127.0.0.1", 6379));` but keep the above line, it works as expected too (but no redis)

Answer (score 0):

For further developments, it is a bug:

https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10624/commits

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9134

It will be fixed soon.